# How do I use requests library with this website?, it keeps giving response 403

Tags: python-requests, http-status-code-403

the link is: https://angel.co/medical-marijuana-dispensaries-1
every time I use `requests.get(url)`, it keeps giving me `403 response`, so I cannot parse it

I tried changing the headers: user-agent and the referer but it did not work

```
import requests

page=requests.get('https://angel.co/medical-marijuana-dispensaries-1')

page

<Response [403]>

session = requests.Session()

session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'})

session.headers

{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

page=requests.get('https://angel.co/medical-marijuana-dispensaries-1')

page

<Response [403]>

page=session.get('https://angel.co/medical-marijuana-dispensaries-1')

page

<Response [403]>
```

Comment: Angel.co is blocking you, try using proxies

Comment: Do you mean changing the proxies?, I tried using an IP from the same country but the answer was: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"